# What does the number on top of a recipe mean?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

When I open my inventory and check recipes for a given material, what does the number at the top of a recipe card mean?

[image: Recipes]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The game simply assigns numbers to the recipes you collect.
Think it as a recipe book, where each recipe has its own page. As you can see the number is in ascending order.